# ResourceID Null

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

why does this work for NSG and not ASG?

```
"networkSecurityGroup": 
 "[if(not(empty(parameters('NICS')[copyindex()].nsgname)), json(concat('{\"id\": \"', 
 `resourceId(parameters('NICS') 
 [copyindex()].nsglocation,'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('NICS') 
 [copyindex()].nsgname), '\"}')), json('null') )]"`


    "applicationSecurityGroups": 
    "[if(not(empty(parameters('NICS')[copyindex()].asg)), 
    json(concat('{\"id\": \"', resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationSecurityGroups', 
    parameters('NICS')[copyindex()].asg), '\"}')), json('null') )]",
```

Err:
"code": "InvalidJson",
"message": "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Networking.Nrp.Frontend.Contract.Csm.Public.ResourceReferenc
eHashSet`2[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Networking.Nrp.Frontend.Contract.Csm.Public.ApplicationSecurityGroup,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Networking.Nrp.Frontend.Contract.Csm.Public.NetworkInterfac
eIpConfiguration]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change
the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath
'properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.applicationSecurityGroups.id', line 1, position 665."
}

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer, the ASG needs an array, so I shimmy'd a `"[" and"]"` before and after the `"{" and "}"`.

```
"applicationSecurityGroups": "[if(not(empty(parameters('NICS') 
[copyindex()].asg)), json(concat('[{\"id\": \"', 
resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationSecurityGroups', parameters('NICS') 
[copyindex()].asg), '\"}]')), json('null') )]"
```